# AWS CloudFormation: EventBridge rule still enabled when 'Enabled: false' is set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-event-bridge

I have an AWS SAM application with a function that contains a `schedule` event, and I wish to conditionally enable/disable the EventBridge rule that is generated for the event based on the value of a parameter.

To do this, I've done the following in **template.yaml** -

1. Added the `FunctionEnabled` parameter, which allows only `[ 'true', 'false' ]` as its value.
2. Added the `EnableFunction` condition, which checks whether `!Equals [ !Ref FunctionEnabled, 'true' ]`.
3. Set the value of the `Enabled` property for the `schedule` event using `!If [ EnableFunction, true, false ]`.

However, when I build the template and deploy it, the EventBridge rule is always enabled, regardless of the value of the `FunctionEnabled` parameter.

```bash
foo@bar:~/sam-project$ sam build -u
foo@bar:~/sam-project$ sam deploy --parameter-overrides FunctionEnabled=true
foo@bar:~/sam-project$ sam deploy --parameter-overrides FunctionEnabled=false
```

Note that the `FunctionEnabled` output correctly shows `true` or `false` based on the value of the parameter, suggesting that the correct boolean value is being passed to the `Enabled` property.

So how can I enable/disable the EventBridge rule based on the value of a parameter?

---

## Update 1

I wondered if the `!If` function might be returning a string rather than a Boolean, so I tried to use the following condition functions as the value of of the `Enabled` property for the `schedule` event.

- `!Condition EnableFunction`
- `!Equals [ !Ref FunctionEnabled, 'true' ]`

However the result is still the same in both cases, so the EventBridge rule is still always enabled.

## Update 2

When I hardcode the value of the `Enabled` property for the `schedule` event to be `false`, the EventBridge rule is disabled as expected.

Does this mean that all of the condition functions return a string as opposed to a Boolean?

---

## SAM Application

#### code/app.py

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context) -> dict:
    return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'AWS-Request-ID': context.aws_request_id,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            'body': '{"message": "Hello World!!"}'
        }
```

#### samconfig.toml

```ini
version = 0.1

[default.deploy.parameters]
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
confirm_changeset = true
```

#### template.yaml

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  FunctionEnabled:
    Description: Whether the EventBridge rule is enabled.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [ 'true', 'false' ]
  Schedule:
    Description: The schedule on which the EventBridge rule triggers the Function.
    Type: String
    Default: cron(0 3 1 * ? *)

Conditions:
  EnableFunction: !Equals [ !Ref FunctionEnabled, 'true' ]

Globals:
  Function:
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    Handler: app.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.8
    Timeout: 1

Resources:
  FunctionLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub "/aws/lambda/${Function}"
      RetentionInDays: 7

  FunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CloudWatch
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: '*'

  Function:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: code/.
      Events:
        ScheduleEvent:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Enabled: !If [ EnableFunction, true, false ]
            Schedule: !Ref Schedule
            RetryPolicy:
              MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 100
              MaximumRetryAttempts: 3
      Role: !GetAtt FunctionRole.Arn

Outputs:
  FunctionEnabled:
    Description: The value of the 'Resources.Function.Properties.Events.ScheduleEvent.Properties.Enabled'.
    Value: !If [ EnableFunction, true, false ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely undocumented, but rather than using `Enabled: true|false`, it's possible to simply use the CloudFormation AWS::Events::Rule property `State: ENABLED|DISABLED`.

It seems that SAM ignores intrinsic functions, so when transforming to CF it see's a value for `Enabled` which it assumes as `true`, and thus the rule is enabled. Note that this behaviour in itself seems different to that described in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-schedule.html#sam-function-schedule-enabled).

> If this property is set to true then AWS SAM passes ENABLED, otherwise it passes DISABLED.

As I didn't get any traction here, I also opened a [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/2482) issue.